# Prove that the sequence $ \frac{ (2^n-1)(2^{n-1}-1)...(2^{n-k+1}-1) } { (2^1-1)(2^2-1)...(2^k-1) }$ is an integer

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, integers

For any given integer $n\ge 1$ and $k \in\{1, 2, \dots, n\},$

$$ F_n(k) = \frac{ (2^n-1)(2^{n-1}-1)...(2^{n-k+1}-1)   } { (2^1-1)(2^2-1)...(2^k-1) } $$

For example, if $n = 1,$ then $k \in \{1\}$ and $$F_1(1) = \frac{2^1-1}{2^1-1} $$

For $n=3,$ then $k\in\{1, 2, 3\}$ and
$$ F_3(1) = \frac{2^3-1}{2^1-1}  = 7 $$
$$ F_3(2) = \frac{(2^3-1)(2^2-1)}{(2^1-1)(2^2-1)} =7 $$
$$ F_3(3) = \frac{(2^3-1)(2^2-1)(2^1-1)}{(2^1-1)(2^2-1)(2^3-1)} =1 $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question.

Comment: Is that really $2^1-1=1$ in the denominator?

Comment: just now, i am trying typing the formula. now it is my problem

Comment: Hint 1:  $\frac {a^{mk} -1}{a^k-1}$ is always an integer (why)?  Hint 2: for any natural $j \le k$ then some of the numbers between $n,n-1,n-2, ....., n-k+1$ will be divisible by $j$.

Comment: @fleablood Just because something is divisible by $2^j-1$ for $j=1,\ldots,k$, it's not necessarily divisible by the product of those numbers. I'd rather suggest to use induction over $n$ and the Pascal-like identity $F_{n+1}(k+1)=F_n(k)+2^{k+1}\,F_n(k+1)$.

Comment: @qfwfq But the "something" is a product if $2^{k_jj}-1$ and if each $2^{k_jj}-1$ is divisible by $2^{j} -1$ then the product $\prod\limits_j( 2^{k_jj}-1)$ will be divisible by $\prod_j(2^j-1)$.  That's not an issue.  But what is an issue is if terms divisible by $2^m-1$ and the terms divisible by $2^j-1$ overlap.  ... This is similar to, I think completely analogous, to proving that any $k$ consecutive integers is divisible by $k!$.

Answer (score 1):

Cobsider $(n)_q:=\frac{q^n-1}{q-1} $, the so called [q-analogue](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog) of $n$. Observe that this is a polynomial of degree n-1 in the variable q.
Define now the q-factorial and the q-binomial as follow:

$$(n)_q!:= \prod_{i=1}^n (i)_q  \qquad \binom{n}{k}_q:=\frac{(n)_q!}{(k)_q! \,(n-k)_q!}$$

It is easy to prove that both are polynomials, for example using the identity
$$
\binom{n}{ k}_q = q^k \binom{n-1}{k}_q + \binom{n-1}{k-1}_q
$$

What you need follows from the evaluation in 2 on the q-binomial.